# Storing a function call inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a javascript program and I want to be able to store function calls that create 3D objects inside of an array. I want to be able to put

```
draw_cylinder(0,0,3,2);
draw_sphere(0,0,5,3);
draw_cone(17,0,7,3);
draw_cube(-1,-1,2, 1,1,3);
```

into array `shapes[]` and then eventually run the program and have each function be called from the array.

Comment: Why don't you create an array of objects and within each object sort the values needed to do the manipulation? So once you need to "run" the program you will have access to the values and would be able to do the draw.

Comment: Are you planning to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be:

```
var a = [];

a.push(function(){ draw_cylinder(0, 0, 3, 2); });
a.push(function(){ draw_sphere(0, 0, 5, 3); });
a.push(function(){ draw_cone(17, 0, 7, 3); });
a.push(function(){ draw_cube(-1, -1, 2, 1, 1, 3); });

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i]();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about putting `function()` in front of each call

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have the functions available in the array or function calls with those specific values?

Just to have the calls, you can do:

```
var a = [];
a.push(draw_cylinder);
a.push(draw_sphere);
a.push(draw_cone);
a.push(draw_cube);

a[2](17,0,7,3);
```

If you want the latter, you'd want to use `bind` to curry the function:

```
var a = [];
a.push(draw_cylinder.bind(null, 0, 0, 3, 2));
a[0](); // will do whatever draw_cylinder(0,0,3,2) does
```

Currying functions - http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html

Bind documentation - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Given how the OP phrased the question, I think the call should be more like `a.forEach(i => i())`

Comment: [_Technically_](http://xkcd.com/1475/), bind does not do _currying_ it just does _partial application_. What currying means is to convert a function `f` : `f(a,b,c,d) -> e` that takes parameters (let's say a,b,c,d) and returns `e` and turn it into a function `f (a) -> (b) -> (c) -> (d) -> (e)`  - that is filling each parameter returns a new function. Passing parameters to a curried function is a form of partial application but the two are not synonyms.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right, though --- Ooh! a rock with a fossil in it!